# Magento 2.3 Admin page error

Tags: magento2

The error I'm getting.

> Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script in C:\xampp\htdocs\onlinestore\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php on line 2

My **validator.php** file

```
<?php 
namespace Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;
use \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File as FileDriver;
```

Anyone knows how I can fix this problem?

Comment: I have the namespace row just below the php tag without spaces so directly to the left.

Comment: It seems like you've edited this file and you have a whitespace in start of this file. Remove the whitespace before namespace. For eg : <?php
namespace Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php

Comment: make sure you are editing it with file encoding UTF-8

Comment: As you add the class as `use` and then frontend slash `(\)` not need. So.`<?php
namespace Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File as FileDriver;`